# Verify call to File.Delete with System.IO.Abstractions.TestingHelpers

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I use the System.IO.Abstractions.TestingHelpers to mock FileSystem. In my class, I inject IFileSystem and use the instance to call _fileSystem.File.Exists and _fileSystem.File.Delete. In my test class, I would like to verify that the "Delete" method was called. It's easy by mocking only the IFile, but since I already mocked the FileSystem, I don't want to have to mock the Directory, Path and File on top of it. Is it possible to call something like `_fileRepository.FileMock.Verify(x => x.Delete(It.IsAny<string>()))`...?

```
public class Downloader : IDownloader
{
    public Downloader(HttpClient httpClient, IFileSystem fileSystem) 
    {
        HttpClient = httpClient;
        FileSystem = fileSystem;
    }

    public async Task DownloadConfigFileAsync(string updatedConfigBaseFolderPath, string configurationFileUrl, string personalAccessToken)
    {
        var newFilePath = FileSystem.Path.Combine(updatedConfigBaseFolderPath, "subfolder1", "myNewFile.txt");
        if (FileSystem.File.Exists(newFilePath))
        {
            FileSystem.File.Delete(newFilePath);
        }

        // rest of implementation ommited for demo purpose
    }
}
```

And my test is like :

```
[Fact]
public async void Given_MissingPathParts_ShouldThrow()
{
    var handlerMock = GetMessageHandlerMock();
    var mockFileSystem = new MockFileSystem(new Dictionary<string, MockFileData>
    {
        { @"c:\Test\", new MockDirectoryData() },
        { @"c:\Test\subfolder1\myNewFile.txt", new MockFileData(string.Empty) }
    });

    var httpClient = new HttpClient(handlerMock.Object);
    var sut = new Downloader(httpClient, mockFileSystem);

    await sut.DownloadConfigFileAsync(BasePath, "http://fakeurl.com?path=%2Fconfiguration%2Flocal%2FTestFile.txt", _fixture.Create<string>());

    handlerMock.Protected().Verify(
        "SendAsync",
        Times.Exactly(1),
        ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req => req.Method == HttpMethod.Get),
        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>());

    mockFileSystem.File.Exists(FilePath).Should().BeTrue();
    
   // Add assertion that the File.Delete has been called
}
```

Comment: Something is not clear, what is `FileSystem.File` ? `File` is not a part of the `IFileSystem` interface. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.ifilesystem

Comment: @ShaharShokrani as OP said - he is using Nuget "System.IO.Abstractions.TestingHelpers" and not Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration


i would also like know answer to this question ...

Answer (score 0):

The test freamwork has extensive unit tests itself.
Looking into ...tests\TestableIO.System.IO.Abstractions.TestingHelpers.Tests\MockFileDeleteTests.cs, it just counts the files, which I don't find overly satisying. If there would be a direct way, the creator would have used it.

```
    var fileCount1 = fileSystem.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*").Length;
    fileSystem.File.Delete(path);
    var fileCount2 = fileSystem.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*").Length;

    Assert.AreEqual(1, fileCount1, "File should have existed");
    Assert.AreEqual(0, fileCount2, "File should have been deleted");
```